# General relativity - Geometric interpretation of Riemannian curvature tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, curvature

I am trying to get a geometric interpretation of the Riemann curvature tensor for 2-dimensional surfaces:
$$R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_X\nabla_YZ-\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$$
In http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor we can find the following equality:
$$\frac{d}{ds}\frac{d}{dt} \tau_{sX} ^{-1} \tau_{tY}^{-1}\tau_{sX} \tau_{sY} \Big|_{s=t=0}=R(X,Y)$$
Where I can get the proof of the last statement?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: See section 6.3 of [these lecture notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/hsr1000/lecturenotes_2012.pdf).

Comment: This is a great little paper for what you're looking for: http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0401099